# Is CharacterEncodingFilter in spring filter Non Ascii characters?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I am using Spring mvc 3.2 and need to filter non-ascii characters from the input.

`web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Using Tomcat, but it is not filtering the Non-Ascii characters. Do we need to write a filter to do the above?

Answer (score 1):

CharacterEncodingFilter sets up character encoding on request and responce, it not filters any input or output, it's filter because it implements http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html interface.